# A question about Euler class in Bott&Tu's book

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

In the beginning of the chapter 11 of Bott&Tu's book *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*, we want to find a global closed form of a sphere bundle $E\rightarrow M$ which restricts to a generator of the cohomology on each fiber. In their book, suppose {$U_\alpha$} is a good cover of $M$, they found a global form of $E$, which restricts to the $d$-cohomology class of $E|_{U_\alpha}$ on all $U_\alpha$, and they claimed that this global closed form restricrs to a  generator of the cohomology on each fiber. I wonder why, wish someone could help.

PS: This problem is equivalent to **a generator of the cohomology of a sphere bundle over a manifold which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R ^n$ restricts to a generator of  the cohomology on each fiber**.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point which you're confused by, but this is the definition of an orientation, it restricts to a generator on each fiber.

Comment: What does “restricts to the $d$-cohomology class of $E|_{U_\alpha}$” mean?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin It just means the restriction of the global form is  a generator of $H^n(E|_{U_\alpha})$(de Rham cohomology). maybe you can get it in problem in 'PS'.

Comment: @Thorgott Maybe you can see the problem in 'PS', I think it is the key of the question.

Comment: @Thorgott You are right, there is another definition of orientation as you said, but local compatibility condition is that any $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ and a 
generator $[\sigma_u]$ of $H^n(E|_U)$ which restricted to the 
fiber $F_x$ is the chosen generator $[\sigma _x]$, here the 'neighborhood' is given. In fact we use another definition of orientation in p114 of Bott&Tu's book.

Comment: Ok, I see the issue now. I'm actually not sure whether I'm missing something or there's a small gap here. One way to see this is by noting that a fiber bundle over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is necessarily trivial, then the claim follows easily from contractibility of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is implicit in the discussion anyway, because why would $H^n(E\vert_U)$ be cyclic otherwise? For the converse, simply start with a trivializing cover and refine it to a good one.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks a lot, I think it is right. For orientation of sphere orientation, I met another problem, I earnestly hope you could check it when you have time. Please! Here is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247565/orientation-of-sphere-bundle