# Orientation of sphere bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

In Bott&Tu's book *Differential forms in algebraic topology*. They give two definitions of orientation of sphere bundle.(p114)

> A sphere bundle with fiber $S^n$, is said to be orientable if for each fiber $F_x$,
> it is possible to choose a generator $[\sigma_x]$ of $H^n(F_x)$ satisfying the local compatibility condition: around any point there is a neighborhood $U$ and a
> generator $[\sigma_U]$ of $H^n(E|_U)$ such that for any $x$ in $U$, $[\sigma_U]$ restricted to the
> fiber $F_x$ is the chosen generator $[\sigma_x]$; equivalently, there is an open
> cover ${U\alpha}$ of $M$ and generators {$[\sigma_{U_\alpha}]$} of $H^n(E|_U)$ so that $[\sigma_{U_\alpha}]$ = $[\sigma_{U_\beta}]$ in  $H^n(E|_{U_{\alpha\beta}})$.

However in p117, they claimed that for a given good cover of $M$, {$\mathfrak U$}， a sphere bundle is orientable if and only if there exists generators on this **given** good cover，{$[\sigma_{\mathfrak U}]$}, satisfying $[\sigma_{U_\alpha}]$ = $[\sigma_{U_\beta}]$ in  $H^n(E|_{U_{\alpha\beta}})$. It is a stronger condition, but they gave no explanation. I want to know how to prove it.

Comment: What if you choose the common refinement of the two covers?

Comment: Is $H^n$ referring to de Rham cohomology (i.e. coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$) or some other choice of coefficients?

Comment: @Kajelad We already know that Čech cohomology is isomorphic to DeRham.

Comment: I believe the chapter should really be read as "Here are some general remarks about good covers. Now if the bundle is orientable and the cover is chosen such that these generators exist, then...". I don't think whether we can do it for a given good cover or not is the point. Anyhow, it still is true. The point is that a good cover is trivializing. So you just have to argue that orientations are represented by a global class on a trivial bundle over a contractible base; this is easy, because all inclusions of the fibers induce isos on cohomology in that case.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you for your detailed explanation, It's true that there's a lot left unexplained, and maybe they should mention that it's provable. I don't know much about the Good Cover theory, so some of the conclusions that seem obvious to Bott are still puzzling to me. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Perhaps generators on a refinement could not give us what we want on$\mathfrak U$, I am not sure about it.